# Ios VOIP background mode without real time conversation

Tags: ios, voip, background-process

My next application will be a chat application(the whatsApp killer :) ) using SIP to deliver all data(text, recorded sound, images, videos ..) and it will include the VOIP in a future version.

Can i use a UIBackgroundModes = voip in the info.plist to let the application run 'for ever' without a risk that Apple reject the app (like the mail client Sparrow) ?

can any one tell me if he use this technique for the same purpose as my application ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're looking for guarantees, no one knows except the person testing the app at Apple, but from Apple's pages; `voip — The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.` which means that you can safely assume they could reject the app if you don't have that functionality (yet).

Comment: No i'm not looking for guarantees, there's no guarantees with Apple, but i want have some feedbacks experiences.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson can you post your answer as answer :) to accept it.